# Does Vision have Computer/Machine type abilities?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

I asked this question on [Movies SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89782/does-vision-have-ai-capabilities-like-ultron/90013#90013) but decided to ask it here as well because I feel it may be better suited here.

As seen in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, Ultron had all the abilities of a Computer/Machine. Going into the internet, absorbing (processing) all of human history, creating "copies" of himself in other robot bodies, etc.

Vision has been shown to be able to "interface?" with technology, when he "hacked" Ultron and locked him out of the internet, but has never shown any abilities like this afterwards.

According to the [MCU Wiki](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Vision#Powers_and_Abilities), he does have the ability:

> Computer Interaction: Vision was able to hack into Ultron's programming and disable the latter's ability to enter the Internet. However, the great effort involved in this task temporarily exhausted Vision, incapacitating him for a short time.

However, he has never shown any other Computer/Machine type abilities in the movies. Is there any other evidence that he may have these types of abilities? Due to his lack of exposure in the movies thus far, I am willing to accept supporting evidence from the comics as well.

Comment: I think AI has a broader definition than given in the question. Self-awareness, mimicking human behavior and the ability to adapt should also be considered.

Comment: `AI type` abilities. I think the wording there is important. Not necessarily being an AI in general. So computer interaction. Internet interaction. Copying himself. Processing data. These are the kinds of abilities I'm referring to when talking about `AI type` abilities. After all, I think its pretty clear that Vision is self aware, especially in the MCU version of the character.

Comment: @JunKang Edit the question (but don't say you did, just work it in like it was always there) and add in the clarifying statements. Comments are ephemeral.

Comment: “AI” doesn’t mean what you appear to think it means. AI (artificial intelligence) refers to a machine’s ability to mimic human intelligence, so Vision’s “AI type abilities” would be his abilities to act like a human. You’re interested in his machine-like abilities—his abilities to act like a computer—which is kind of the exact opposite.

Comment: This is not migration, as your question is still on Movies, but reposting, which is discouraged. Actual migration can be done by mods.

Comment: I don't understand everyone's nitpicking about my question on `AI Type` abilities. I clarified what I meant in the question about the types of abilities I mean. `Going into the internet, creating copies of himself, etc.` I didn't ask if he is an AI. I asked if he has those abilities that AI's tend to have commonly in sci-fi, movies, tv, etc, such as interacting with computers/machines. But I edited the question because of everyones' insistence.

Comment: And @Mithoron I apologize, I was incorrect to use the term migration. It is a repost, with the stipulatation that I don't want only answers specific to movies and tv, thus I felt it may be better suited here, where other sources of media may be used, ie. comics, etc, although the question did originally come from my curiosity of this character from the movie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Comics:**

The Vision's powers in the comics are, according to [Comic Vine](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/vision/4005-1504/) (I've added emphasis to his computer-like capabilities):

> The Solar Jewel on the Vision's forehead absorbs ambient solar energy to provide the needed power for him to function, and he is also capable of discharging this energy as optic beams; with this, he can fire beams of infra-red and microwave radiation. In extreme cases he can discharge this same power through the Solar Jewel itself which amplifies its destructive effects considerably, albeit at the cost of losing most of his resources. The Vision also possesses the ability to manipulate his density, which at its lowest allows flight and a ghostly, phasing intangibility, and at its heaviest provides superhuman strength, immovability, and a diamond-hard near invulnerability. The Vision is capable of reaching a density ten times greater than that of depleted uranium. On one occasion, the Vision uses this extreme durability to render unconscious the villain Count Nefaria. The Vision often uses his ability to alter his density against foes, by phasing an intangible hand through them and then partially re-materializing it—a process he describes as "physical disruption." This effect typically causes great pain and results in incapacitation, as is the case when used against the Earth-712 version of the hero Hyperion. Being an artificial life-form/android of sorts, the Vision possesses multiple superhuman senses—as well as superhuman stamina, reflexes, speed, agility, and strength (even without being at high density). The Vision was trained in unarmed combat by Captain America, and is an expert in the combat use of his superhuman powers. **The Vision is an expert on his own construction and repair,** and is a highly skilled tactician and strategist. The Vision controls his density by interfacing with an unknown dimension to/from which he can shunt or accrue mass, thus becoming either intangible or extraordinarily massive. **The Vision also possesses superhuman analytical capabilities, and has the ability to process information and make calculations with superhuman speed and accuracy.**

That's a lot of powers, but very little of it comes from his <s>positronic</s> synthezoid brain. So it seems that The Vision can *think* like a computer, but can't really *act* like one in the same way that Ultron can.

---

**MCU:**

On the big screen, Vision's computer-related abilities seem to have been dialed up a bit.  As you mentioned, in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* he was able to hack into Ultron's operating system.  We don't know much beyond that, however.